# MVC3 Form submit single input to Action with list parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, input, defaultmodelbinder

I have a third party control that utilizes a single hidden input field to store a list of integers. This control is used throughout the site on numerous forms.

The submitted value (as displayed in Fiddler) is:

```
items=1,35,346,547
```

The controller action looks like:

```
public ActionResults SomeAction(IEnumerable<int> items) {...}
```

As expected, the DefaultModelBinder fails to parse the list of integers. Given that I do have the ability to change the format of the input value, is there a format that would enable the default model binder to parse this for me?

I could easily change the action to have a string parameter and handle the parsing myself, however I'd like the model binder to do this for me. I could also intercept the form submit and scrape/change the data/data-type to JSON (or someother format), however I'd really like to avoid this approach. Another option would be to create a custom model binder, but this seems like it might be a bit of overkill.

Recommendations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Description

No the Default Model Binder can't do this. You can create a custom Model Binder that handle that. Asuming your input field name is `items` my sample should work, if not change it to the right name.

#### Sample

```
public class MyCustomModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        List<int> result = new List<int>();

        var value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("items").AttemptedValue;

        foreach (string i in value.Split(",".ToCharArray()))
        {
            int a;
            if (Int32.TryParse(i, out a))
                result.Add(a);
        }
        
        return result;
    }
}

public ActionResult SomeAction([ModelBinder(typeof(MyCustomModelBinder))] List<int> list)
```

#### More Information

- [Custom Model Binders in MVC 3 with IModelBinder](http://buildstarted.com/2010/09/12/custom-model-binders-in-mvc-3-with-imodelbinder/)
- [ASP.NET MVC Custom Model Binding](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=584)
- [DefaultModelBinder Sourcecode](http://www.koders.com/csharp/fidE24AB01CA23B54FD204C5C493366C19A282025DD.aspx?s=ajax)

### Update

You can register your Custom Model Binder in `global.asax`

```
  ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(List<int>), new MyCustomModelBinder());
```

but be aware that this would always try to bind if you have `List<int>` in your Action Method.

#### According to your comment: There is no way, at the moment, that makes it possible to say the Default Model Binder to do that because he try to bind the properties and don't know when you want to bind `List<int>`and when not.

You can see the source of the [`DefaultModelBinder` here](http://www.koders.com/csharp/fidE24AB01CA23B54FD204C5C493366C19A282025DD.aspx?s=ajax)

Comment: My understanding is that this is true only for the case when submitting multiple input fields. 

For instance:
`items : 1
items : 35`

Or:
`items=1&items=35`

Unfortunately, in my case I'm using a single input field with comma separated ints. In other words, the query string parameters would be `items=1,35,346,547`

Comment: Ah ok, sorry a mistake. i change my answer

Comment: My answer is updated now. Please try it and let me know if you need more / other help

Comment: This is definitely a valid solution. However, as mentioned in the original post I'm hoping to avoid custom model binders. This control is used in numerous places throughout the site and posts to a number of different controller actions. In some cases these actions accept the IEnumerable<int> parameter, whereas in other cases the action accepts a more complex type parameter that may have a child property of IEnumerable<int> that needs to be bound. Long story short, if I can avoid registering a global model binder I'd like to. Hopefully that makes sense. Thanks again for your suggestion!

Comment: There is no way, at the moment, that makes it possible to say the Default Model Binder to do that because he try to bind the properties and don't know when you want to bind List<int>and when not.

Comment: Check out the source of the `DefaultModelBinder`